# How to create an image from byte array and display it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I want to get data from an image file and display that information in a texture that Unity can read.

I am able to get the pixel information into a byte array, but nothing ever displays on the screen. How do I actually get the image to display?

```
     pcxFile = File.ReadAllBytes("Assets/5_ImageParser/bagit_icon.pcx");
     int startPoint = 128;
     int height = 152; 
     int width = 152; 
     target = new Texture2D(height, width);
     for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
         for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
         {
             timesDone ++;
             pixels[x, y] = new Color(pcxFile[startPoint], pcxFile[startPoint+1], pcxFile[startPoint+2]);
             startPoint += 4;
             target.SetPixel(x, y, pixels[x, y]);
         }            
     }
     target.Apply();
     target.EncodeToJPG();
```

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-display-a-texture2d-onto-a-canvas.336949/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried both of the options here and they still don't work. So I asked for more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, (assuming you get the pixel data correctly) you have to asign that created texture to something...

I'ld use e.g. a [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html) since it doesn't need a `Sprite` (as the `UI.Image` component would do - also see the [RawImage Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html)):

```
// Reference this in the Inspector
public RawImage image;

//...

pcxFile = File.ReadAllBytes("Assets/5_ImageParser/bagit_icon.pcx");
int startPoint = 128;
int height = 152; 
int width = 152; 
target = new Texture2D(height, width);
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        timesDone ++;
        pixels[x, y] = new Color(pcxFile[startPoint], pcxFile[startPoint+1], pcxFile[startPoint+2]);
        startPoint += 4;
        target.SetPixel(x, y, pixels[x, y]);
    }            
}
target.Apply();
// You don't need this. Only if you are also going to save it locally
// as an actual *.jpg file or if you are going to
// e.g. upload it later via http POST
//
// In this case however you would have to asign the result 
// to a variable in order to use it later
//var rawJpgBytes = target.EncodeToJPG();

// Assign the texture to the RawImage component
image.texture = target;
```

Alternatively for using with normal `Image` component create a `Sprite` from your texture using [`Sprite.Create`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html):

```
// Reference this in the Inspector
public Image image;

// ...

var sprite = Sprite.Create(target, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, target.width, target.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

image.sprite = sprite;
```

---

**Hint 1**
In order to have the correct aspect ratio I used a little trick usually:

1. Create a parent object for this RawImage
2. Set the desired "maximal size" in the `RectTransform` of the parent
3. Next to the `RawImage`/`Image` (on the child object) add an [`AspectRatioFitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.AspectRatioFitter.html) (also see the [AspectRatioFitter Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html)) and set `AspectMode` to `FitInParent`.
4. Now in the code adjust the aspect ratio (you get it from the texture):

   ```
   public RawImage image;
   public AspectRatioFitter fitter;

   //...

   image.texture = target;

   var ratio = target.width / target.height;
   fitter.aspectRatio = ratio;
   ```

---

**Hint 2**
It is "cheaper" to call [`SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) once for all pixels than calling `SetPixel` repeatedly:

```
// ...

startPoint = 0;
pixels = new Color[width * height]();
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = new Color(pcxFile[startPoint], pcxFile[startPoint+1], pcxFile[startPoint+2]);
    startPoint += 4;
}

target.SetPixels(pixels);
target.Apply();

// ...
```

(I don't know how exactly your `pcx` format works but maybe you could even use [`LoadRawTextureData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html)

Comment: Thanks, I finally got the image to display, but my data from the pcx file is way wrong.

Comment: Yeah you seem to not read the correct info. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCX): 1. There is a 128 byte header you didn't take into account. 2. You have to check the type (compression, bit depth, with or without palette etc). 3. Seems that you forgot the alpha channel

Comment: [This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=684049) is for Java but it might help you to figure out how to write a correct PCX importer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the pcx format mentioned, but I think there is a less convoluted way to do this now, based on a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/92257/loading-png-file-and-using-it-for-unityengine-ui-image) on the gamedev StackExchange.

```
target = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
target.LoadImage(byteArray);
```